# Groovy: How to get certain files from HDFS based on filePattern

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want to get  only  those files  from  HDFS  directory  which contains certain name (  i have  put  several response  file   with name  like  this  2017-090-0.1,
2017-090-0.2,2017-090-0.3  and  etc.  now  i  want to  be  sure  that  certain amount  of  flowFile is put  in  hdfs (  I MEAN IF  I SEND  3  REQUEST  WITH  RELATED  NAME  I  WILL  HAVE  TO  CHECK  IF   I  HAVE  PUT  THREE  RESPONSE IN   HDFS )   for  this case   i  use  this  code  below,  BUT  IT  DEOSN'T  FETCH    FILES  there  are  several subejects  i  am interested in :

1. Is   it  possbile to make   this  task  without groovy  code  by nifi  capabilities?
2. WHAT  SHOULD I  CHANGE  TO MAKE  THIS CODE   WORK?

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
   import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
   def flowFile= session.get(1);//  i  gues  it  will   return    list  of  
   flowfiles
   def name="";
   def  count=0;
   def  value=0;
   def  amount=0;
   List<FlowFile> flowFiles = new ArrayList<FlowFile>();
   for(def  n in  flowFile){
   name=n.getAttribute("realName")
   count=n.getAttribute("count")
     value=count as  Number
     value=Math.round(value)
   }
   session.remove(flowFile)
   def findFileRecursive( String directoryName, String filePattern) {
   def fileFound
   def directory = new File(directoryName)
   if (directory.isDirectory()){
   def findFilenameClosure = { if (filePattern.matcher(it.name).find()){  fileFound = it } }
   directory.eachFileRecurse(findFilenameClosure)
   }
   amount++;
   flowFiles.add(fileFound);
   return fileFound
   }
   String filePattern=filePattern.contains(name)
   String  directoryName="/group/test/userDate";
   findFileRecursive(directoryName,filePattern);

   if(amount==count){
   for(def m in flowFiles){
   session.transfer(m,REL_SUCCESS);
   }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `GetHDFS` processor which will retrieve these files from HDFS storage with verifiably working code and route the resulting flowfile to either the `success` or `failure` relationship. You do not need to write any custom code to perform this task. `PutHDFS` will then perform the write back to HDFS if necessary.

Comment: how  can  i  use  filepattern in  getHdfs  as  i  remember  i  can  only  write  directory  adress  and hadoop  configuraton  details

Comment: I  need   to   retreive  file   which  name  contains  the  string  like  this :"2017-01-01" ,  how  can i  write in  GetHdfs

Comment: Simply  can  i  write   something   like  this   when  i  got flowfiles   from   getHdfs processor  if(flowFile.getAttribute('filename').substring(0,10)=="2017-01-01"){session.transfer(flowfile,REL_SUCCESS)}else{session.rollback(flowFile)}

Comment: There is a property called *File Filter Regex*. You’ll need to provide it a value like `\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}` which will match any series of 4 digits, then a dash, then 2 digits, a dash, and 2 more digits.

Comment: If you want to match a specific string of characters, just provide them as literals, escaping the `-` characters. Example: `2017\-01\-01`